# Missing 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' on DELETE with Spring MVC and Boot

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot, cors

I'm having a really weird error and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something fairly simple, but after a couple of hours, I can't seem to be closer to the solution.

I have a REST endpoint with method DELETE, built with Spring MVC and Spring Boot. The implementation is as simple as this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/job/{id}", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteJob(@PathVariable("id") String id) {
    jobRepository.delete(id);
}
```

I'm calling this from angular js with

```
$http.delete(backendHost + 'job/' + id)
```

But when I execute the code, I get

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://localhost:8080/job/578b6e40d2823043482dbdf9. Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed
>   access. The response had HTTP status code 403.

My cors headers are set and allow any origin:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**")
                        .allowedOrigins("*")
                        .allowedMethods("GET", "OPTIONS", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This is a problem only for the delete method. It works fine for any other method. If I change the request to a GET instead of a DELETE, it works perfectly.

Also, it only fails when invoking the delete endpoint from my angularjs client. If I call the exact same endpoint from a web based rest client such as Postman, it works fine. It forces me to set `allowedMethods`, though, which I didn't think it would need to be set if I wanted everything.

I'm sure I'm missing something extremely basic here. Any ideas?

Comment: try `$http.delete('job/' + id)`

Comment: That would only work if I set a default prefix for $http, which I haven't. Anyway, the called url is correct, as the error message I pasted shows:  http://localhost:8080/job/578b6e40d2823043482dbdf9

Comment: Did you ever find a solution ?

Comment: this happened to me AFTER I enabled spring security. Even after removing spring security completely this is still happening.. arg!